# VBA : save the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, save

I'm beginner in VBA, I would like to know if my code is efficient. I'm wondering that is to long, maybe there is some function to save the spreadsheet?

I'm proceeding like this :

1. I click on the button (the code runs the Userform "Edition Fichier"), the name of this Userforme in my code is uSauvegarde.

[image]

2. I make my choices :

[image]

3. The code is :

   ```
   Private Sub bParcourir_Click()
   With Application.FileDialog(4)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    uSauvegarde.TextBox1 = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    End Sub
    Private Sub bValider_Click()
    Dim wb_Saisie As Workbook, wb_Sauv As Workbook
    Dim New_Wkb As String, TableDesFeuilles() As String
    Dim i As Integer, NumF As Integer
    Dim S As Worksheet
    Dim obj As Shape
    Dim mdCalc As XlCalculation
    mdCalc = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    New_Wkb = uSauvegarde.TextBox1 & "\" & uSauvegarde.TextBox2 & ".xlsx"
    Set wb_Saisie = ThisWorkbook
    wb_Saisie.Activate
    i = 0
    For Each S In wb_Saisie.Sheets
    If S.Visible = True Then
        ReDim Preserve TableDesFeuilles(i)
        TableDesFeuilles(i) = S.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    NumF = 0
    BlocageModif = True
    For Each S In wb_Saisie.Sheets
    If S.Visible = True Then
        S.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        If NumF = 0 Then
            Set wb_Sauv = ActiveWorkbook
            NumF = 1
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Move After:=wb_Sauv.Worksheets(NumF)
            NumF = NumF + 1
        End If
        Range("A1").Select
        For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            If ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Hidden = True Then ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Delete
        Next
        For j = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If ActiveSheet.Rows(j).Hidden = True Then ActiveSheet.Rows(j).Delete
        Next
        For Each obj In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If obj.OnAction <> "" Then obj.OnAction = ""
        Next
    End If
    Next S
    For Each NomLocal In wb_Sauv.Names
    If InStr(NomLocal.Name, "Print_") = 0 Then NomLocal.Delete
    Next
    wb_Sauv.SaveAs Filename:= _
    New_Wkb, FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, 
    CreateBackup:=False
    wb_Sauv.Close
   Application.Calculation = mdCalc
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   MsgBox ("Fichier enregistré")
   uSauvegarde.Hide
   End Sub
   Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1")
    uSauvegarde.TextBox2 = "Mon_fichier"
   End With
   End Sub
   Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
   uSauvegarde.TextBox2 = ""
   End Sub
   ```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good to me, but I found some things that didn't make any sense like a `With` that created more code or turning off Screen updating where it was already turned off. The code was difficult to read because of bad indentation and lack of descriptive variable names. This is really important when coding because is HIGHLY possible you will need to read it again to fix possible bugs or make it more efficient. I made some changes for you to review.

```
Option Explicit '---- always good to have

Private Sub bParcourir_Click()

    With Application.FileDialog(4)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        uSauvegarde.TextBox1 = .SelectedItems(1)
     End With
     
 End Sub
 
 Private Sub bValider_Click()
 
 Dim wb_Saisie As Workbook, wb_Sauv As Workbook
 Dim New_Wkb As String, TableDesFeuilles() As String
 Dim i As Integer, NumF As Integer
 Dim S As Worksheet
 Dim obj As Shape
 Dim mdCalc As XlCalculation
 
 mdCalc = Application.Calculation
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
 New_Wkb = uSauvegarde.TextBox1 & "\" & uSauvegarde.TextBox2 & ".xlsx"
 
 Set wb_Saisie = ThisWorkbook
 
 wb_Saisie.Activate
 i = 0
 
 For Each S In wb_Saisie.Sheets
    If S.Visible = True Then
        ReDim Preserve TableDesFeuilles(i)
        TableDesFeuilles(i) = S.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If
 Next
 
 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False ---- why disable "screen updating" again?
 NumF = 0
 BlocageModif = True
 
 With ActiveSheet '----- a "With" here is a good idea
 
 For Each S In wb_Saisie.Sheets
    
    'If S.Visible = True Then
    If S.Visible Then '------- the if statement above can be written like this

        S.Copy
        .Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        If NumF = 0 Then
            Set wb_Sauv = ActiveWorkbook
            NumF = 1
        Else
            .Move After:=wb_Sauv.Worksheets(NumF)
            NumF = NumF + 1
        End If
        
        Range("A1").Select
        
        For i = .UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            
             If .Columns(i).Hidden Then
                t.Columns(i).Delete
             End If
             
        Next
        
        For j = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
          
            If .Rows(j).Hidden Then
                .Rows(j).Delete
            End If
            
        Next
        
        For Each obj In .Shapes
    
             If obj.OnAction <> "" Then
                obj.OnAction = ""
            End If
             
        Next
        
    End If
    
 Next S
 
 End With
 
 For Each NomLocal In wb_Sauv.Names
    If InStr(NomLocal.Name, "Print_") = 0 Then NomLocal.Delete
 Next
 
 '------ this section of the code has problems.. check it out
 wb_Sauv.SaveAs Filename:= _
 New_Wkb, FileFormat:= _
 xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False,
 CreateBackup:=False
 
 wb_Sauv.Close

Application.Calculation = mdCalc
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'MsgBox ("Fichier enregistré") '----- parenthesis are nor necessary
MsgBox "Fichier enregistré"

uSauvegarde.Hide

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

'With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1") ---- this "With" creates more code...
    'uSauvegarde.TextBox2 = "Mon_fichier"
'End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").uSauvegarde.TextBox2 = "Mon_fichier"

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    uSauvegarde.TextBox2 = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, It is better to write : 
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

uSauvegarde.TextBox2 = "Mon_fichier"

End Sub

Comment: I mean without : ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1"). in fron of "uSauvegarde"

Comment: with Option Explicit I have an error that some variable in the function bValider_Click(), I'm wondering wich one, it seems like I declared all variables. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @Marie It's difficult for me to help you because I don't have the file but did you know you can run the code line by line? and you can position the cursor over the varibales to see what values are assigned. In Windows is with `F8` and in Mac `command + shift + i` Another thing, I modified the IF statements. Try to write them like that. When you write them without the End If it can cause some problems. Also, there is a problem in the last section of the code I wrotte something there so you can find it. `Option Explicit` is there to help you if is bothering you just delete it.